# Add thousand separators to chartist.js

Tags: reactjs, chartist.js

So I'm trying to add thousand separators to graph numbers, made with npm package chartist. The way I'm trying to implement that is next:

```
    const data = {
          // A labels array that can contain any sort of values
          labels: this.props.labels.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."),
          // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
          series: [this.props.data]
        };
```

I tried to change the package itself but every time I get the next error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of object '[object String]'
        at String.push (<anonymous>)
        at Object.Chartist.normalizeData (chartist.js:400)
        at constr.createChart (chartist.js:3387)
        at constr.initialize (chartist.js:1940)
```

Also I tried to implement this as a function:

```
    function(label){label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}
```

But then it's showing that data.labels(from the npm package) is not a function.

**EDIT 1:**
If I console.log(this.props.labels) then I get [this log in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Ug6.png)
The graph numbers I pasted there with a package names chartist-plugin-tooltips, so maybe I have to change something there, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to run `.push` against a String, instead of an array. I assume that labels should be an array, but `.replace` is going to return a string.

Perhaps you intended to convert your labels back to an array using [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
From toString() you will have a string that is a comma-separated list of your array values. So you will have to split it again using the commas. For example

```
labels: this.props.labels.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".").split(',')
```

**Edit**

If your array values have commas, you will need to use a different separator with `.join`, instead of `.toString`.

```
    this.props.labels.join('$').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".").split('$')
```

**Final edit**

If you are not actually adding values to the array, it would be much cleaner to map through the elements! I realised this a bit late when I read your question again.

```
this.props.labels.map(label => label.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."))
```

Comment: it's not showing errors, but the numbers don't have commas. Maybe I'm not placing it where it should be ?

Comment: If the numbers in the array have the character "," in, then split(',') is going to create additional unwanted elements for each comma. So 2,5 will be split into two elements in the array. Try using .join instead of toString to control the separating character. 
(see edit)

Comment: If i try the final edit it's showing the error: "label.replace is not a function"

Comment: @AlexandraTiganciuc Oh because each element is a number and not a string... 
this.props.labels.map(label => label.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "."))

Comment: I found a problem:)
I tried to console log label, cause it didn't do anything
And label was just indexes and if I console.log label.value then it's undefined

Comment: I don't understand why

Comment: It seems like this.props.labels is not a list of numbers like I assumed. So you need to inspect the list that you send as a prop in the component's parent. Or maybe try logging this.props.labels.

Comment: I send as a props data object, which contains labels and series array. const data = {
      // A labels array that can contain any sort of values
      labels: this.props.labels.map(label =>
        console.log(label.value)
      ),
      // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
      series: [this.props.data]
    };

Comment: can you please edit your question showing the results if you log this.props.labels?

Comment: Edited, you can look up now